# when creating icons that will be used as SVGs, is it important to have shapes occupy whole pixels rather than a portion of it?

Tags: vector, svg, icon

I understand that if you have shapes taking only half of a pixel in an image, it will look blurry as a rasterized image. Since ill be using them as svgs and glyphs will the same problem retain?

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. If you use a vector application then some process down the line is going to do the rendering. This system will likely anti-alias the result. Anti-aliasing is a trade off between blurring and ringing. Since most vector engines seem to work by using a box filter the result is always more or less blurred since box filtering is in the very blurring spectrum of anti-aliasing reconstruction filters.

Now since we can not distinguish between anti aliasing and blurring you can opt to say that the image is blurred. Only it may be better than the aliased very sharp image so some say the anti-aliased image is sharper, since in fact your eye and brain assume images are always more or less blurred and sharpen the result anyway.

The same effect persists no matter what since all images you see are anti-aliased anyway.

Answer (score 1):

All screens use pixels to display any image, vector or otherwise. Therefore all screens will anti-alias partial pixels in all instances.

Comment: Yes and some filters anti-alias even pixels that are complete. Since their filter size is bigger than one pixel. They will conversely ring which may make the image sharper though.

Comment: Possibly @joojaa Not 100% certain what you are referring to though. Can you explain more... perhaps in chat?

Comment: ok moved to chat